# Linking data from list to turtles NetLogo

Tags: excel, netlogo

I have a question. I have start using NetLogo recently and I have to finish an assignment for my study with NetLogo, however I have a problem. 
I want to use data from an Excel file in a model. The dataset contains two rows of numbers each row representing a different variable, say a and b, and I want to assign to each turtle a set of those two variables, so that each turtle has a value for variable a and b. However I have no idea how to do this.
I’ve succeeded in loading the dataset into the model by converting it to a txt file. The rows in the .txt file are divided by a tab.
This is de code I used for loading the dataset in the model:

```
 globals [ turtle-data ]
 turtles-own [ awareness income housingtype adopt ]
 to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 11557
  ask turtles [
   set color white
  ]
  ask turtles [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
 load-turtle-data
 assign-turtle-data
end
to load-turtle-data
  ifelse ( file-exists? "input-data.txt" ) [
    set turtle-data []
    file-open "input-data.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ][
       set turtle-data sentence turtle-data (list (list file-read file-read))
    ]
   user-message "File loading complete!"
   file-close
   ]
   [
      user-message "There is no input-data.txt file in current directory!" 
   ]
end
to assign-turtle-data
  assign-income  
  assign-housingtype
end
to assign-income
  foreach turtle-data [
  ask turtles [ set income item 0 ? ]
  ;link to turtle-data
 ]
end
to assign-housingtype
  foreach turtle-data [
  ask turtles [ set housingtype item 2 ? ]
  ;link to turtle-data
 ]
end
```

How can I link the values in the dataset to the right variables of the turtle? Alternative solutions for my problem are also welcome.

Comment: Search this forum for NetLogo and CSV.  Also, see https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/notes/netlogo-intro.xhtml#file-based-input

Comment: Alan, I think he's got the file input part right already, or it looks like it. The question, as I understand it, is about the `assign-income` and `assign-housingtype` procedures. `ask turtles` in those isn't right; he wants to ask one turtle at a time. But how?

Answer (score 3):

Nice job figuring out the data import part. I've actually been working on an extension to do exactly that, but it looks like you don't even need it! Now, for your question:

Rather than creating a bunch of turtles (I assume there's one per data row), I would create the turtles one-by-one as you iterate through the data:

```
to setup-turtles
  foreach turtle-data [
    crt 1 [
      set income item 0 ?
      set housingtype item 1 ?
    ]
  ]
end
```

This simplifies the problem of assigning the data to individual turtles without having to deal with indices or `who` numbers (which other solutions require). It also makes it so that the number of turtles will automatically adjust if you add or remove data.